# QT - How to send a file using https?

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, https

I've been reading about [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and I cannot figure out how to properly setup an ssl connection and send a file over. I have no experience in networking whatsoever, so maybe i'm missing something obvious?

This is my attempt so far (I removed some clutter):

```
QUrl url("https://.........");
url.setUserName(username);
url.setPassword(password);

QNetworkRequest request(url);

QSslConfiguration sslConf = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
sslConf.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
QSslConfiguration::setDefaultConfiguration(sslConf);
request.setSslConfiguration(sslConf);

QFile *file = new QFile(filepath);
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray fileContent(file->readAll());

QNetworkReply* reply = manager->post(request, fileContent);
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506223/qnetworkrequest-with-ssl-local-certificate With local certificate you should be able to do it less complex and BTW do "verify none" mode only if you sure.

Comment: @AlexanderV I downloaded the certificate (I'm trying to upload a file to a hololens, and I downloaded its certificate), and I set it as local certificate, but I get an ssl error when I verify it that says "The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted"

Comment: I recall not doing any specific actions with SSL and no certificate in the program code and still being able to invoke https requests from Qt. Attempt without all that but `manager->post()`.